# QGIS V. parallel command using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I cannot offset a line to a specific decimal place, (ie only whole numbers can be inputted) 
Am I missing something here??

Comment: the documentation for v.parallel says you  an input decimals. http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.parallel.html . What tool are you using to do this in QGIS?